# Why can we cast sockaddr to sockaddr_in

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, udp

I can see why it is useful to cast `sockaddr` to `sockaddr_in`, but I don't understand how this is possible.  From what I've read, they're the same size and `sockaddr_in` is added with `sin_zero` to make it the same size.  I would like to know how the compiler knows where to get the information from `sockaddr_in` if it is layed out differently to `sockaddr`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is possible because you normally cast pointers, not the structures themselves. You do what in natural language means "please treat this pointer to a `socket structure` as a pointer to an `internet socket structure` instead". Compiler has no problems to re-interpret the pointer.

Here is more detailed description taken up from comments:

A `sockaddr` is 16 bytes in size - the first two bytes are the `sa_family`, and the remaining 14 bytes are the `sa_data` which is arbitrary data. A `sockaddr_in` is also 16 bytes in size - the first 2 bytes are the `sin_family` (always `AF_INET`), the next 2 bytes are the `sin_port`, the next 4 bytes are the `sin_addr` (IP address), and the last 8 bytes are the `sin_zero` which is unused in IPv4 and provided only to ensure 16 bytes. This way, you can look at `sockaddr.sa_family` first, and if it is `AF_INET` then interpret the entire `sockaddr` as a `sockaddr_in`.

A `sockaddr_in` is not stored inside of `sockaddr.sa_data` field. The entire `sockaddr` is the entire `sockaddr_in` (when `sockaddr.sa_family` is `AF_INET`, that is). If you take a `sockaddr*` pointer and cast it to a `sockaddr_in*` pointer, then:

- `sockaddr.sa_family` is `sockaddr_in.sin_family`
- bytes 0-1 of `sockaddr.sa_data` are `sockaddr_in.sin_port`
- bytes 2-5 are `sockaddr_in.sin_addr`
- bytes 6-13 are `sockaddr_in.sin_zero`.

Comment: It seems odd because the variable that is supposed to store the address in sockaddr is sa_data which is char[14], yet sockaddr_in uses an unsigned short.  I'm assuming that the compiler would read the first unsigned short number of bytes from the char[14] and make that the address, and the rest of char[14] is the data to be sent?

Also, if I add the sizes of the two structs, they don't appear to be the same size.  sin_zero seems too big.  I'm just tring to get what's going on here!

Comment: A `sockaddr` is 16 bytes in size - the first two bytes are the `sa_family`, and the remaining 14 bytes are the `sa_data` which is arbitrary data.  A `sockaddr_in` is also 16 bytes in size - the first 2 bytes are the `sin_family` (always `AF_INET`), the next 2 bytes are the `sin_port`, the next 4 bytes are the `sin_addr` (IP address), and the last 8 bytes are the `sin_zero` which is unused in IPv4 and provided only to ensure 16 bytes.  This way, you can look at `sockaddr.sa_family` first, and if it is `AF_INET` then interpret the entire `sockaddr` as a `sockaddr_in`.

Comment: A `sockaddr_in` is not stored inside of `sockaddr.sa_data` field.  The entire `sockaddr` **is** the entire `sockaddr_in` (when `sockaddr.sa_family` is `AF_INET`, that is).  If you take a `sockaddr*` pointer and cast it to a `sockaddr_in*` pointer, `sockaddr.sa_family` is `sockaddr_in.sin_family`, bytes 0-1 of `sockaddr.sa_data` are `sockaddr_in.sin_port`, bytes 2-5 are `sockaddr_in.sin_addr`, and bytes 6-13 are `sockaddr_in.sin_zero`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I hope you can edit your post and add the useful content of the comments inside ( especially the second comment that treats how the struct fields are interpreted ) It'll be more clear and more specific.

Comment: @MichaelHeidelberg: No problem, I did it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Great! Thank you, that's well explained.

Comment: How does sturct padding figure into this? What gives guarantees that the two structs have similar alignment between their members in so far pointer to one can be used in place of pointer to another?

Comment: @amn: Have a look at declarations side by side. You will see how the fields are defined similarly in the beginning and map one to one perfectly, then different declarations are different interpretations of the same data (in case of casting). The structures are defined in the way that guarantees accurate mapping.

Comment: I think the real question is: Is it guaranteed that `sizeof(struct sockaddr) == sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)` (and other address families like `sizeof(struct sockaddr) == sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)`)?