# What care the parameter sizeof(sockaddr_in)

Tags: c, assembly

In functions as `connect()` the last parameter is the size of the `sockaddr_in` structure.

All well, but `sin_zero` is unused (the system doesn't "pop sin_zero" as I understood in [stackoverflow.com/questions/28280581/how-kernels-recognize-sin-zero-sockaddr-in-structure-pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280581/how-kernels-recognize-sin-zero-sockaddr-in-structure-pushed)), so for what the functions need this parameter?

I.e. asm or when C is compiled to asm, the RET of connect() must specify the number of bytes to delete (RET n), bytes that are the connect() arguments. Why n is a fixed number (don't change I specify the sin_zero or no) if I can push or no sin_zero in asm and assign value to sin_zero in C. And if I create a program in asm and I don't push sin_zero to the stack, the programs works perfectly... but n is the same number!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pop sin_zero"? What you should pass to `connect` is a `sockaddr*`. There's nothing that says that the `sockaddr` struct has to be stack-allocated, nor should the `connect` function care.

Comment: Hint: these functions accept `struct sockaddr*` but you are normally passing a different thing altogether, `struct sockaddr_in*`. Do you know why?

Comment: Michael: I'm saying "pop sin_zero" refering to when the function finish' sin_zero is subtracted from the stack.

Comment: n.m.: I prefer use sockaddr_in.

Comment: `RET n` is the stdcall convention, linux and C in general uses cdecl where the caller pops the arguments and the caller knows how many bytes it pushed. Even for stdcall, in this case the argument is a pointer (as you have been told above) so the argument size is fixed at the pointer size, unrelated to the struct size.

Comment: @Rob I don't think you understand the problem here. If you look at the prototype of `connect` in the documentation, you see something like `int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);` But you are not using `struct sockaddr`, you are using `struct sockaddr_in`. It's not merely because you "prefer" to, it's because you want to connect over *an internet* (`_in` stands for 'internet').

Comment: Jester: "is fixed at the pointer size", but building the structure in asm I push the family, the port and the address and no more and move esp to my pointer. The pointer don't know when finish. The connect() function is who access to [esp+ determinated_n].

Comment: n.m.: I'm saying these strcutures are equivalent, but the problem is in these 8 bytes that are trash, not in the structure.

Comment: "I'm saying these strcutures are equivalent". Not really, they are not.

Answer (score 2):

A `sockaddr_in` is a structure containing an internet address. This structure is defined in `<netinet/in.h>`. This is server/client address `struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;` Here is the definition:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    short   sin_family;
    u_short sin_port;
    struct  in_addr sin_addr;
    char    sin_zero[8];
};
```

`sin_family` – use AF_INET
`sin_port` – port number (in network byte order => use `htons(port)`)
`sin_addr` – Internet address described by struct `in_addr`

```
struct in_addr {
        unsigned long s_addr;
};
```

Set `s_addr` to INADDR_ANY => local internet address.
`sin_zero[]` – set to `0` with `bzero()` or `memset()`. Padding to make structure the same size as `SOCKADDR`.

bind() example

```
int mysock,err;
struct sockaddr_in myaddr; 
mysock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
myaddr.sin_port = htons( portnum );
myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
bzero(&(myaddr.sin_zero),sizeof(myaddr.sin_zero));
err = bind(mysock, (struct sockaddr *) &myaddr, sizeof(myaddr));
```

I have found some info about `sin_zero` (Unix network programming chapter 3.2)

> The POSIX specification requires only three members in the structure: sin_family, sin_addr, and sin_port. It is acceptable for a POSIX-compliant implementation to define additional structure members, and this is normal for an Internet socket address structure. Almost all implementations add the sin_zero member so that all socket address structures are at least 16 bytes in size.

And the definition of `sin_zero`

```
unsigned char  __pad[__SOCK_SIZE__ - sizeof(short int)
                    - sizeof(unsigned short int) - sizeof(struct in_addr)];
};
#define sin_zero        __pad
```

> Most of the net code does not use sockaddr_in, it uses sockaddr.  When you use a function like sendto, you must explicitly cast sockaddr_in, or whatever address your using, to sockaddr.  sockaddr_in is the same size as sockaddr, but internally the sizes are the same because of a slight hack.

That hack is sin_zero.  Really the length of useful data in sockaddr_in is shorter than sockaddr.  But the difference is padded in sockaddr_in using a small buffer; that buffer is sin_zero.

On some architectures, it wont cause any problems not clearing sin_zero.  But on other architectures it might.  Its required by specification to clear sin_zero, so you must do this if you intend your code to be bug free for now and in the future.

Please, have a look at [page](https://silviocesare.wordpress.com/2007/10/22/setting-sin_zero-to-0-in-struct-sockaddr_in/).

Comment: Nice answer. I've edited the post specifying more because I don't know how process sin_zero.

Comment: What? I'm speaking of how the system process sin_zero, value assigned or no.

Comment: I found quite interesting example of using sin_zero. [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-517.3.15/bsd/netinet/ip_divert.c?txt) In `sin_zero` you can put some additional data. _you can look at sockaddr.sa_family first, if it is AF_INET then interpret the entire sockaddr as a sockaddr_in_ [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312113/why-can-we-cast-sockaddr-to-sockaddr-in)

Answer (score 1):

I think, kernel uses size parameter to see your sockaddr is ipv6 address or not because ipv6 address size is bigger than other net address in linux and unix.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the architecture issue, on different architecture like 64-bit / 32-bit size of primitive declared in the `sockaddr_in` will be different. That's why it may be a parameter declared in the `connect()` function.